# Strong Markov property and time homogeneity

Tags: probability-theory, markov-chains, conditional-expectation, stopping-times, filtrations

Let $X$ be a Markov chain with state space $\mathcal{S}$ and denote $\mathbb{N} := \{ 0, 1, \cdots\}$. We know that for any stopping time $\tau < \infty$ and any bounded measurable function $\phi : \mathcal{S} \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$, there exists a function $\psi : \mathbb{N}\times \mathcal{S} \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that

\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}[\phi(X_{\tau+1}) \; | \; \mathcal{F}_{\tau}] = \psi(\tau, X_{\tau})
\end{align}

I need to show that $X$ is temporally homogeneous if and only if, for all $\tau$ and $\phi$, the above $\psi$ does not depend on $\tau$ (namely it takes the form $\psi(X_{\tau})$).

I am trying to use smoothing property of conditional expectation to solve this:

\begin{align}
\mathbb{1}_{\{\tau = n\}} \; \mathbb{E}[\phi(X_{n+1}) \; | \; \mathcal{F}_n] &= \mathbb{1}_{\{\tau = n\}} \; \mathbb{E}[\phi(X_{n+1}) \; | \; X_n] \\
&= \mathbb{E}[\phi(X_{\tau+1}) \; | \; X_{\tau}] \\
&= \psi(X_{\tau})
\end{align}

I cannot figure out if I have implicitly used time homogeneity here. I also don't know how to establish the sufficiency (how time-homogeneity results from sole dependence of $\psi$ on $X_{\tau}$). I would appreciate any insights on this.

Comment: Why repost an exact copy of a question you already asked (and that people commented)?

Comment: @user2348674: I also noticed that your acceptance rating is zero :-(
You won't get as much attention if you do not ever accept answers.

Comment: @Did My previous question[link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1771678/strong-markov-property-proof) was on the proof of strong Markov property whereas this question is on time-homogenous implications of Strong Markov property.

Comment: @par Thanks for pointing that out; I am relatively new here and did not know that I need to do that. Thanks :) !

Comment: @user2348674: you should go back and accept some answers; it will help your cause.

Comment: @user2348674 A question on exactly what you call "time-homogenous implications of Strong Markov property" was posted recently with the same typographical and notational choices and some basic blunders in it were signalled. Now as then, $\mathbb{1}_{\{\tau = n\}} \; \mathbb{E}[\phi(X_{n+1}) \; | \; X_n]= \mathbb{E}[\phi(X_{\tau+1}) \; | \; X_{\tau}]$ is simply impossible.

Comment: @Did I would appreciate it if you send me the link to that question; I am searching for that too ...

Comment: In discrete time, the strong Markov property is a trivial (if important) consequence of the simple Markov property. To involve it in a discussion of time-homogeneity simply clouds the issue. 
To start to answer your question, what (precisely) do *you* mean by "temporally homogeneous"?

Comment: By "temporally homogeneous" I mean the simple time-homogeneous property of Markov chains: $P(X_{n+1} = j \; | \; X_n = i) = P(X_1 = j \; | \; X_0 = i)$ for all $n \ge 0$.

Comment: So you are assuming the state space $S$ to be countable?

Comment: Yes, $\mathcal{S}$ is countable here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, because $X$ is a Markov chain, there is a function $p:\Bbb N\times S\times S\to[0,1]$ such that $\Bbb P[X_{n+1}=j\,|\,\mathcal F_n] = p(n,i,j)$, a.s. on $\{X_n=i\}$, for each $(n,i,j)\in \Bbb N\times S\times S$. And $X$ is temporally homogeneous if and only if $p(n,i,j) = p(m,i,j)=p(i,j)$ for all $(i,j)\in S\times S$, for all $m$ and $n$.

**Added:** This answers "I need to show that $X$ is temporally homogeneous if and only if, for all $\tau$ and $\phi$, the above $\psi$ does not depend on $\tau$ (namely it takes the form $\psi(X_{\tau})$)." If $X$ is temporally homogeneous, then $\Bbb E[\phi(X_{n+1}\,|\,\mathcal F_n]=\sum_{j\in S}p(X_n,j)=:\psi(X_n)$ doesn't depend on $n$. From this it follows by conditioning on the value of $\tau$ that $\Bbb E[\phi(X_{\tau+1}\,|\,\mathcal F_\tau]=\psi(X_\tau)$.

Conversely, if   $\Bbb E[\phi(X_{\tau+1}\,|\,\mathcal F_\tau]=\psi(X_\tau)$ for all $\phi$ and $\tau$, then taking $\phi=1_{\{j\}}$ and $\tau=n$ (non-random) we have   $\Bbb P[X_{n+1}=j\,|\,\mathcal F_n]=\psi_j(X_n)$ for some function $\psi_j$ with values in $[0,1]$. Consequently, $\Bbb P[X_{n+1}=j\,|\,X_n=i]=\psi_j(i)$. Define $p(i,j):=\psi_j(i)$ and note that $\sum_jp(i,j)=1$. It follows that $X$ is temporally homogeneous.

Comment: Is this an answer to the original question I posted? Seems to me this is only the definition of temporal homogeneity of a Markov chain ....